# Color the space between tr's

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give a color to the space between the rows.
This is the result:
http://gyazo.com/88b855df698f55d1e8c7350a31f4d51b
[image]

What I have done is the following:

```
#PersSchemaTable td:nth-child(1),
#PersSchemaTable td:nth-child(3), 
#PersSchemaTable td:nth-child(5), 
#PersSchemaTable td:nth-child(7), 
#PersSchemaTable td:nth-child(9), 
#PersSchemaTable td:nth-child(11),
#PersSchemaTable td:nth-child(13) {
    border-right: 2px solid #781351;
}
```

As you can see there is still spacing between each row. Btw the table is made in php.
How can I color the space between the rows too?

Comment: Are you talking about coloring only the space between the bottom and top edges two adjacent rows of table cells? how about the space between the left and right edges of the cells?

Comment: Yea I'm talking about the space between the bottom and top edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the entire table a background color and then assign each `<td>` the background color you want them to be.

Comment: But now the whole table is covered, can I somehow prevent the background in some spaces? I can't just change the background of everything...

Comment: you can easily change the backgrounds of every child element of the table, like `<tr>` and `<td>` with CSS

Answer (score 1):

Set the `position` of your cells to `relative` and then use an absolutely positioned pseudo element.

Here's a *very* rough example, assuming a 5px gap between your cells:

```
td{
    position:relative;
}
td:nth-child(2n-1)::after{
    background:red;
    bottom:-5px;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:-2px;
    top:-5px;
    width:2px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the previous solution is easier and better. Thank you very much again ^^

Comment: I'm confused. The answer you accepted changes the colour surrounding every cell yet the code you provided in your question indicates that you're looking to have a line to the right of only certain cells.

Comment: The code I posted is an example for my question. The answer was good and I gave me a good idea of doing it. I know it might be a bit dirty but as long as it works and doesn't take a lot of time then it's good. I voted up for your answer too ^^

Comment: In that case, please update your question to clarify that what you have provided is there only to illustrate the problem and not as an example of what you wish to achieve.